# Does frequently executed expression get its result cached?

Tags: java, c++, caching, compiler-optimization, cpu-cache

```
for (int i = 0; i < foo + bar; ++i)
{
      // do something
}
```

Suppose that `foo + bar` is a huge number and that its value does not change during the loop iterations. (That is, the loop's body doesn't alter `foo` or `bar`)

Does the value of `foo + bar` get cached somewhere? Or does it get re-evaluated everytime?

Would C/C++ handle it differently from higher level languages, such as Java?

Comment: Pick a language in 1st place. The behavior might be very different.

Comment: well, I did mention Java and C++

Comment: You could try replacing `foo + bar` with the actual number, play around with it, and see which one takes the longest and how big the difference actually is.

Comment: This misses some details. What is `foo` and what is `bar`?  Is the `operator+` function involved inline (perhaps even builtin?) and does the address of `foo` and `bar` escape the loop or not, are they even globals/file-scopes?

Comment: Um, Java is not a "higher level language" compared to C++, except in the fever dreams of Java-heads.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C++ language specification does not require any specific optimizations from a particular compiler implementation.

Having said that, if your compiler can figure out that the result of this additionl is invariant, it will likely do that.

Whether or not your C++ compiler is capable of this optimization, of course, depends your compiler. You can examine the resulting object code, using your platform's disassembler, to determine how your code was compiled, and figure out the answer yourself.

If you would like to be certain that this kind of optimization takes place, you are free to "help" your compiler by doing this yourself, by making the appropriate changes to the code.

Answer (score 7):

Neither Java nor C nor C++ speaks to the question, except to the extent that all of them *permit* an implementation to optimize by lifting the computation out of the loop, so as to perform it once for all, provided that the compiler (C / C++) or the JVM's JIT compiler (Java) can prove that the expression is indeed invariant.

The optimization you describe is a well-known one, however, and it is likely to be performed by implementations of all three languages if you do not disable optimization.